# Executions and Causality Requirements in JMM

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

Here
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.8

what does it mean
 hbi|Ci = hb|Ci

soi|Ci = so|Ci

and
For any read r in Ai - Ci-1, we have hbi(Wi(r), r)

why do they substruct Ai from Ci-1 - or it is some sort of range?

what is sufficient synchronizes-with edges for Ei?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what does it mean hbi|Ci = hb|Ci, soi|Ci = so|Ci

Maybe you've missed the definitions at the top of the section you reference:

> We use f|<sub>d</sub> to denote the function given by restricting the domain of f to d. For all x in d, f|<sub>d</sub>(x) = f(x), and for all x not in d, f|<sub>d</sub>(x) is undefined.
>
> We use p|<sub>d</sub> to represent the restriction of the partial order p to the elements in d. For all x,y in d, p(x,y) if and only if p|<sub>d</sub>(x,y). If either x or y are not in d, then it is not the case that p|<sub>d</sub>(x,y).

> > For any read r in Ai - Ci-1, we have hbi(Wi(r), r)
>
> why do they substruct Ai from Ci-1 - or it is some sort of range?

This is set subtraction, it means elements in A<sub>i</sub> not also present in C<sub>i-1</sub>.

> what is sufficient synchronizes-with edges for Ei?

I am not 100% sure here, but it probably means the set which is sufficient to establish the full synchronization order. Basically, for any pair of sw-edges *sw(a,b)* and *sw(b,c)*, an additional *sw(a,c)* would be redundant (beyond sufficient).

### Update

Actually, I've missed the formal definition immediately below the use of the term:

> `8.` Let ssw<sub>i</sub> be the sw<sub>i</sub> edges that are also in the transitive reduction of hb<sub>i</sub> but not in po. We call ssw<sub>i</sub> the sufficient synchronizes-with edges for E<sub>i</sub>. If ssw<sub>i</sub>(x, y) and hb<sub>i</sub>(y, z) and z in C<sub>i</sub>, then sw<sub>i</sub>(x, y) for all j ≥ i.

That means that all sw-edges which can be inferred from program order (po) are also removed.